# Postgres select join json query

Tags: postgresql, join, query, json

I have a problem to make a postgres query with join from data of json.

I have 2 tables

The first one is media:

- id as integer
- path as string

and an other table `playlist`

- id as integer
- media as string (with my json inside)

For example

Media:

```
1   /img/a.jpg
2   /img/b.jpg
3   /img/c.jpg
4   /img/d.jpg
5   /img/e.jpg
```

Playlist:

```
1   ["1", "2", "5"]
2   ["4", "2", "3", "1"]
```

I want to make an SELECT on playlist and get back all path ideally as json or if not possible something like (example for playlist 1):

```
1   /img/a.jpg
2   /img/b.jpg
3   /img/e.jpg
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to "unnest" the elements of the JSON array and then join that to your media table:

The following query assumes that `media` is a column of type `jsonb`. If that is not the case (which it should be) you need to cast it `media::jsonb`.

```
select m.id, m.path
from media m
  join (  
    select jm.id::integer as media_id
    from playlist p
      cross join jsonb_array_elements_text(p.media) as jm(id)
    where p.id = ? --<< your playlist id here
) t on m.id = t.media_id;
```

`jsonb_array_elements_text(p.media)` returns all elements of the array as rows and  `as jm(id)` defines a table alias for that result giving the column that is returned the name `id`. The expression `jm.id::integer as media_id` then converts the string value into a proper integer so it can be used in the join condition.

---

Unrelated, but: this is a case of [unnecessary JSON](http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-anti-patterns-unnecessary-jsonhstore-dynamic-columns/). If you normalize your data model, queries like that will be a lot easier and more efficient. Plus: you can define proper foreign key constraints between playlist and media.

Comment: Thank you, in my project, each playlist is editable with some media and each playlist must be played on different screens. For example in my room 1 only the 3 media from the first playlist in another room are displayed the four media from the second playlist.

how to put a media list in each playlist without using JSON or Array? knowing that each is playlist is unique, independent and can contain 1 or 100 media

Your querry working great but is display all media of all playlist. I have try to put an WHERE in "from playlist p" but not working ^^

thx

Comment: @Greg: see my edit